# String in JSON message body blocked by Azure WAF with OWASP 3.1 returning 403

Tags: xss, sql-injection, cors, waf

### Details

I have an application running behind an Azure Web Application Firewall (WAF) on an Azure Application Gateway (AppGW) that was previously on an on-premises server. Since moving it to Azure, users and testers are now getting 403 Forbidden when attempting to send data to the service. I believe these are seen by the WAF as XSS or SQL Injection attacks, but I don't have a way to prove it.

So the question is, why are these requests being blocked by a WAF?

Note: These curl commands were generated by Postman. I took the JSON document and put it into a function.

Example callers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function json_document() {
  cat <<EOF
{
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "xxyyzz",
      "codeType": "aaabbbccc",
      "description": "some random string with >48 stuff, here"
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    {
      "vendorName": "a company",
      "url": "https://my.company.com/app/SSO/",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

/usr/bin/curl \
  --location \
  --request POST \
  --url 'https://my.company.com/v1/csharp/app/resource' \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_PAT}" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw "$(json_document)"
```

The above curl command works if I remove the `>` and replace it with `&gt;`. Then the second example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function json_document() {
  cat <<EOF
{
  "name": "Item One (3 TIMES A DAY) (deferiprone) - Prior Authorization",
  "attributes": [
        {
      "vendorName": "Vendor Name",
      "url": "Vendor URL",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

/usr/bin/curl \
  --location \
  --request POST \
  --url 'https://my.company.com/v1/csharp/app/resource' \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_PAT}" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw "$(json_document)"
```

The above works when we remove the `DAY) (` portion or put it in a different spot in the string, which breaks some formatting rules later on.

Both of these get the following result:

```
<html>
  <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
  <body>
    <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
    <hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Question

Why are these being blocked for seemingly innocent strings?

Comment: I'm afraid `--data-raw` is not the right option, you should just the simple `--data`. With that, your first request is passed. But the second one triggers an error: `[id "933210"] [msg "PHP Injection Attack: Variable Function Call Found"] [data "Matched Data: (3 TIMES A DAY) (deferiprone) found within ARGS:name: Item One (3 TIMES A DAY) (deferiprone) - Prior Authorization"]`

Comment: Sorry, looks like some other rule triggered in your case - in 3.1, there wasn't the mentioned rule (933210). But unfortunately I do not have any 3.1 rule set...

Comment: @airween, how did you test that? I generated this curl call from Postman, so I didn't change the command very much beyond putting the JSON in a function.

Comment: I have many running ModSecurity instance, and could check your request. For eg. if you have Docker, you can try https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/modsecurity-crs or, but it doesn't seem to have 3.1 either. The other way is to use CRS Sandbox: https://coreruleset.org/20211209/introducing-the-crs-sandbox/. It works without any installation, but perhaps the 3.1 is missing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Docker, you can try [CRS ModSecurity Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/modsecurity-crs), but it doesn't seem to have CRS 3.1. The other way is to use [CRS Sandbox](https://coreruleset.org/20211209/introducing-the-crs-sandbox). It works without any installation, but perhaps the 3.1 is missing too. With these, you can check which rules were triggered.

Comment: It seems that the first cURL call is seen as a SQL Injection Attack: SQL Tautology Detected. I'll accept this answer, but my calls that are in the example are seen as SQL Injection Attacks plus too many SQL character sequences found.

Comment: Check out my answer posted as well

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution proposed by [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/265398/61945) to figure out how to run the `docker.io/owasp/modsecurity-crs:nginx-alpine` container using Podman to test my calls.

So, I created this Kubernetes Deployment Manifest to have Podman play.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: owasp-crs-demo
  labels:
    owasp: crs-podman
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: owasp-crs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: owasp-crs
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: owaspcrsexample
          image: docker.io/owasp/modsecurity-crs:nginx-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              hostPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
              name: crs-http
          env:
            - name: BACKEND
              value: http://127.0.0.1:5000
            - name: PARANOIA
              value: 5
        - name: philapp
          image: philflaskapp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
              name: flask-http
...
```

I then used the following command to bring up the Pod.

```
podman play kube --build --replace k8s-owasp-crs-setup.yaml
```

My `philflaskapp` is located here:

```
➜  k8s-owasp-crs-examples git:(main) 
> tree
.
├── README.md
├── Taskfile.yaml
├── examples
│   └── output
│       ├── modsecurity-crs-finding-output.json
│       └── modsecurity-crs-finding-output.yaml
├── k8s-owasp-crs-setup.yaml
├── philflaskapp
│   ├── Containerfile
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── phil_flask_app.cpython-310.pyc
│   └── phil_flask_app.py
└── tags

4 directories, 9 files
```

Then I ran the bash script in the OP description. You should recieve:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.20.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

To view these logs, use the following command:

```
podman logs owasp-crs-demo-pod-0-owaspcrsexample
```

From here, it may seem like a lot of jibberish, but if you copy out the Nginx access logs, you can use Vim and `python -m json.tool` to parse the JSON so it's readable. These should help you identify any WAF rule matches.

You can find the code above in this GitHub repository:

- https://github.com/FilBot3/k8s-owasp-crs-examples

Comment: @airween This is the answer that I came up with. This helped me and my developers figure out what they were doing wrong and could fix in their application to better avoid these matches.

Comment: thank, and congratulation! Also it's really-really good to see that you could solved this issue. I really hope that I could help something :)